Reconciling Continuity of Binary Relations with Continuity of Functions/Correspondences
I asked this question in the Economics StackExchange as well, but figured it may be better-suited here.
There are various ways to express the concept of continuity of a binary relation, but one I've come across seems to imply the closed-graph property is sufficient. That is to say:
For a nonempty set $X$ endowed with a topological structure, a relation $R$ on $X$ is (closed) continuous if it is a closed subset of $X \times X$.
If $X$ is a metric space, an equivalent definition is:
If $(x_{m}), (y_{m}) \in X^{\infty}$ are sequences satisfying $x_{m} \rightarrow x$, $y_{m} \rightarrow y$, and $x_{m} R y_{m}$, for each $m$, then $x R y$.
Where the implication is that $R$ contains all its limit points and is thus closed in $X \times X$. I've seen this definition applied to preference relations as well, where a preference relation was defined as a binary relation satisfying

Reflexivity: For all $x \in X$, $x R x$
Transitivity: For all $x, y, z \in X$, if $x R y$ and $y R z$ then $x R z$
Connectedness: For all $x, y \in X$, $x R y$, $y R x$, or both

But we can formally define functions and correspondences as binary relations satisfying the total property. That is:
If $R$ is a self-map/self-correspondence on $X$ (I use self-map here for consistency with most preference relation setups), then for all $x \in X$, there exists a $y \in X$ such that $(x, y) \in R$ (equivalently, $x R y$ or $R(x) = y$).
Where functions additionally satisfy the functional property, which specifies that each value in the domain maps to just one value from the range:
If $(x, y) \in R$ and $(x, z) \in R$ (equivalently, $x R y$ and $x R z$, or $R(x) = y$ and $R(x) = z$), then $y = z$.
In the context of correspondences, we are told that the closed-graph property does not necessarily imply upper hemicontinuity (which reduces to continuity of single-valued functions), unless the range set is additionally compact. But in the above definition of continuity of a binary relation, no reference to the compactness of $X$ is made. The examples I've seen for correspondences generally referred to singleton-valued correspondences, so I wonder if the functional property is part of the issue.
So my question is, why does the closed-graph property appear to be sufficient for continuity of a binary relation, but not for correspondences or functions? Is it assumed when we discuss binary relations that the functional property does not come into play? Do we generally mean something slightly weaker when we refer to continuity of preference relations?

For simplicity I'll assume $X$ is a metric space.
Given a function $f:X\to X$, continuity of relation $xRy$ iff $y = f(x)$ means that if $(x_n, y_n)\to (x, y)$ where $y_n = f(x_n)$ implies $f(x) = y$. which is weaker than assuming $x_n\to x$ implies $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. In the former you assume that $f(x_n)$ already converges, but continuity says that $x_n\to x$ must imply that $f(x_n)$ converges.
Same holds for topological spaces if we replace sequence $(x_n)$ by an arbitrary net $(x_i)$.
For example, let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x}, & x\neq 0\\ 0, & x = 0\end{cases}$, then $f$ is not continuous, yet its graph is closed. For example, $x_n = \frac{1}{n}\to 0$ but $f(x_n) = n$ doesn't converge at all.

So if I understand correctly, this definition of continuity of a binary relation is a weaker form of “continuity”, in that we are ignoring cases in which $(y_{m})$ does not converge at all? If we assert the connectedness property I noted above (e.g. no longer a function by definition). Would the closed-graph property be sufficient for an equivalent form of continuity?

For your first question, yes. For your second question, the relation $R$ coming from a function $f$ is almost never connected in the sense that either $xRy$ or $yRx$ for $x, y\in X$. If it is, then necessarily $X$ has at most one element. So while this would work, its also too trivial to be useful in any way.

Sorry, what I now have in mind is the use of binary relations in economics to represent preferences across all elements of a set. So in my hypothetical the binary relation does not satisfy the definition of a function, but the singleton result makes sense to me if we assert the functional property above.
